# Postgresql query deletes all rows

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

I wrote a simple `delete` query in a PostgreSQL function with `using` clause, `left join` and a `where` clause. But the query does not take the `where` condition in consideration. It deletes all rows.

I wrote two types of query both produce same result

**Query 1**

```
delete from "StockInfos" using "StockInfos" as si
    left outer join "PurchaseOrderInfos" as poi on poi."Id" = si."PurchaseOrderInfoId"
    left outer join "ReceivingInfos" as ri on ri."PurchaseOrderInfoId" = poi."Id"
 where ri."Id" = (delete_data->>'Id')::bigint;
```

**Query 2**

```
delete from "StockInfos" where exists (
            select * from "StockInfos" as si
                left join "PurchaseOrderInfos" as poi on poi."Id" = si."PurchaseOrderInfoId"
                left outer join "ReceivingInfos" as ri on ri."PurchaseOrderInfoId" = poi."Id"
            where ri."Id" = (delete_data->>'Id')::bigint
        );
```

I don understand what is the problem. May anyone tell what is going wrong?

Comment: From which table does `delete_date` come from?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @GMB from "StockInfos"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rephrase this with a correlated subquery. This makes the logic much cleaner, and should do what you want:

```
delete from "StockInfos" si
where exists (
    select 1
    from "PurchaseOrderInfos" poi
    inner join "ReceivingInfos" as ri on ri."PurchaseOrderInfoId" = poi."Id"
    where 
        oi."Id" = si."PurchaseOrderInfoId"
        and ri."Id" = (si.delete_data->>'Id')::bigint

)
```

Comment: ops! sorry delete_data is a parameter of the postgres function type of jsonb which contains an `ReceivingInfoId` which should match with the `Id` 's of "ReceivingInfos" table

Comment: How ever this query works perfectly. Thanks a lot. what does select 1 means, may you please tell?

Comment: @Ajmal-Hossain: `exists` just cheks if the subquery returns *something*. Since we don't need the actual resultset, we use `select 1`. That's merely a convention (it could be `select 0`, `select *`, or `select null`...).